# Can I use an IP address of another PC in my PC to connect to the internet?

Tags: networking, vpn, ip

If PC1 is in Country1 and PC2 is in Country2, is it possible for PC1 to enter the IP address that PC2 uses to  connect to the internet to show up itself in Country2? If so, how?

Note: I am talking about a manual thing, don't using VPN apps or services/servers.

Comment: If PC2 has a wireless connection, they can share that to PC1 via a Mobile Hotspot setup.

Comment: @John, PC! and PC2 are in different countries. If still you think your idea works please explain more?

Comment: Wireless connection sharing will only work if the computers are close enough to each other; that is, on  a border. If truly remote from each other, I don't think you could simply connect by IP address (different ISPs)

Comment: I don't understand the question, are you trying to connect PC1 to PC2 together... How or for what purpose? What are you trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot do this.  You can only connect to the IP in the address ranges allotted to you by your ISP.  Putting in an IP outside of the allowable range and not assigned to you, will result in an error.

If one could just enter in any IP address they wanted, there would be no way for data to be routed to you.